# javascript button onClick do not wait for function return true and opens the link

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

```
<a class="btn btn-info" href="home/delete" onclick="return confirmDelete()">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit icon-white"></i>
    Delete
</a>
```

The `confirmDelete` function opens the page and do not wait for the return function. My function is:

```
function confirmDelete(){
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
    if (result) {
        console.log("User confirmed dialog");
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log("User declined dialog");
        return false;
    }
});
```

but the code below is working properly and waits for the ok to open the link.

```
<a class="btn btn-info" href="home/delete" onclick="return confirm()">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit icon-white"></i>
    Delete
</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because there is no way to wait for a call like window.confirm does. You need to use the call back for confirm and set the window location to do the navigation for you.

```
<a class="btn btn-info "  href="home/delete" onclick="return confirmDelete(this);">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit icon-white"></i>Delete</a>
```

and the changes to your script

```
function confirmDelete (anchor) {
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
        if (result) {
            window.location.href = anchor.href;
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

NOW as a warning using a GET request to make a deletion is a BAD BAD BAD idea. If a webcrawler or a link preloader hits the page, it will make a request to the anchors and wipe out your data.

Comment: Thanks , It worked :) and also i modified my original code of href it is being encrypted before being sent with get means instead of href="home/delete" its href="home/delete/asjfaskdjfksljfksafsaf" (some ID) :)